# BMW 5-series F10 when car is parked relay or something triggers shock sensor

Tags: bmw, relay, alarm

I have weird issue with my BMW F10. 2011 530d xDrive to be exact. the problem is that when car is parked shock sensor is triggers from time to time. I have CCTV camera so I see that nobody is around, but in the car there is a dash camera and it records some noise. this happens like up to 3-4 times per 24 hours, sometimes only once. Any ideas of what that could be?

Video from the dash camera: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ja96lrljMO0

Comment: Is there any possibility that there are some environmental factors that are causing this?  Seismic activity, local construction, local road traffic, etc.?

Comment: Electrical noise from something somewhere might trigger it (like airport radar) , or it has a faulty supply filter in the sensor.

Comment: no seisicactivity here, no nearby construction at night, and traffic is low, ant almost none at night. this also happens at underground parking so dont think it some kinds of radars may affect it. and airport from my home parking is like 15kilometers away

Comment: Then the sensor or system may simply have a fault in it.  Unfortunately taking it to a dealer will probably be expensive but there is likely not much in the way of other choices.  You might try locating the sensor and see if it's mounted properly.  You might also purchase a new sensor and swap it out.